# How to hide the password while opening the master key on DB restore : SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, encryption

I know that, when a DB is restored then in-order to use the decrypted data its DMK needs to be reopened with following query.

OPEN MASTER KEY DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = ''

ALTER MASTER KEY ADD ENCRYPTION BY SERVICE MASTER KEY

CLOSE MASTER KEY

Now the issue is, the DB restore is performed by scripts and pretty much automated. Now after encryption I cannot include the above commands in the script as it will include the password in plain Text. Is there any way to hide this password, or to re-open the DMK without the password?

Comment: Have you had any solution? I'm facing the same problem